What does 'poison dry' mean?
I was watching this YouTube video when on minute 26:58 the speaker said

...they were tripping on poison dry.

While I did not understand the whole sentence, this 'poison dry' was particularly puzzling. I tried to google, didn't find much apart from this cosmetic product, whose name also didn't make sense to me, however. Any ideas?

A few seconds later the presenter refers to it as "ergot poisoning" in an appositive construction.  "... because that would have been a lot of poison dry, of ergot poisoning, going around."

@TimR oh my, I didn't even understand those two were related... I got a sense that 'poison dry' is a somewhat fixed term in English for something more general

I had never heard the expression poison dry until today.  I can vouch that it's not an everyday term by any means.

@TimR, thanks for sharing!

@TimR - 'poisoned rye' is much more common, I promise you. When I was a kid there was a brand of soda ('pop') called Canada Dry, but although I think it was bad for your teeth, it wasn't actually poisonous.

That woman certainly moves her hands a lot! Pretty annoying.

When I was a psychedelic hippy around 1968, we knew all about C. purpurea and similar things (cactuses, mushrooms, toad sweat, etc).

I have 100% faith in AI-generated subtitles.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a one-off instance of poor quality auto-generated subtitles

Despite the subtitles, the woman in the video says that they were tripping (having a psychedelic experience) on (having consumed) poisoned rye.
Rye is a type of grain grown to make flour for bread since ancient times. Sometimes the growing rye grains can become infected with a type of fungus or mould ('mold') called ergot (Latin name Claviceps purpurea). The fungus contains a number of strong psychedelic substances including ergotamine, and the condition of being affected or poisoned by the fungus is called ergotism or ergot poisoning. The most usual way of being poisoned is to eat bread made with flour from infected rye grains. Ergot can also infect other grains such as wheat, barley and (rarely) oats.

The ergot fungus contains a number of highly poisonous and
psychoactive alkaloids, including lysergic acid (LSD), which was
synthesized from the ergot fungus in 1938 by chemist, Albert Hoffmann.
Ergot poisoning is a proposed explanation of bewitchment. Most
historians today believe that the witchcraft trials that led to
thousands of deaths and burnings at the stake in Europe during the
Dark Ages were likely related to outbreaks of ergot poisonings. The
unfortunate victims of the Salem witch trials of 1692 also exhibited
symptoms of ergot poisonings. Ergotism is rare today due to careful
screening of cereal grains.

Ergot: the psychedelic fungus (US Forest Service)

Yes this makes sense - unless you were trying to really enunciate the difference between "poison dry" and "poisoned rye", those two phrases would sound identical from most native speakers. The YouTube caption auto-generator guessed wrong, presumably because "rye" is a much less common word than "dry".

@CanadianYankee - it totally sounded like 'poisoned rye' to me, but maybe I was primed to hear that. I expected it before I went to the video.

@MichaelHarvey The historian in the Video said that the theory was wrong. The phrase suggests the idea that people during the witch trials might have been "tripping" (hallucinating) due to consuming contaminated grain. However, the historian dismisses this theory, explaining that widespread ergot poisoning was unlikely because it would require a massive amount of contaminated grain.

@JamesMathai - epidemics of ergotism have been documented since the 7th century CE.

@MichaelHarvey thank you so much for your answer! Although I rewatched this part a few times, hoping to understand what the speaker was saying, I didn't catch (and would not catch without your help, for sure) that what she said was actually 'poisoned rye'. Thanks for taking the time to watch the video and explain this to me!
